# Print module theming address for user page

Tags: 7, theming

I am using the [print module](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) to have print-friendly pages. I followed theme suggestions, I could not make the theming work for user pages. So far, I tried the following I would like to theme user pages for printing but I could not figure out how.

```
print--html--user.tpl.php
print--html--user--%.tpl.php
print--html--page--user.tpl.php
```

Example pages to view theme suggestions, [here](http://chakraco.club/print/user/1437) and [here](http://chakraco.club/user/1437).

Answer (score 0):

The Print module only works for nodes. You can use the [Entity Print](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print) module for Drupal 7.

You can read [Entity Print / Usage](https://www.drupal.org/node/2430561) to understand how to override the default template.

> **Overriding Templates**
>
> You can copy the entity-print.tpl.php template into your theme to take control of the global PDF template.
>
> If you wish to have per entity type templates you can do so by implementing hook_theme() for different entity type keys, for example:
>
> ```
> function MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
>   return array(
>     'entity_print__commerce_order' => array(
>       'base hook' => 'entity_print',
>       'template' => 'entity-print--commerce-order',
>     ),
>   );
> }
> ```